# How come this regex isn't working?

Tags: regex

I am using:

```
"<a\b[^>]*href=\"\\lyrics\\*\">(.*?)</a>";
```

And I'm trying to find the value under these paremeters:

```
     <a href="/lyrics/anything.html">This is what I need</a>
```

I need to find the "This is what I need" but the "anything" changes depending on the link. I don't want to find the text inside all the 'a' tags but, only ones of which have are inside the lyrics folder. I can't see why this currently isn't working? I'm awful at explaining but thanks in advance. Oh and I understand regex perhaps isn't the best method but, I really want to look into it.

Comment: <a\b[^>]*href=\"\/lyrics\/*\">(.*?)</a>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are escaping `\\` instead of using `/` (it is `/lyrics/` not `\lyrics\`.

Additionally, `\\*` will match 0 or more `\` characters, when you should be matching on any character that is not `"`.

The following will do:

```
"<a\b[^>]*href=\"/lyrics/[^\"]*\">(.*?)</a>"
```

Comment: I needed to use <\/a> as I kept recieving an error but, thanks for stepping me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Your slashes are the wrong way around (i.e. those which make up the path) and you're missing a dot before the *:

```
<a\b[^>]*href=\"/lyrics/.*\">(.*?)</a>
```

Comment: There is usually no need to escape `/`.

Comment: Ahh - thanks Oded; I've always used them without a problem so never realised they were superfluous - removed (which basically means I've now got your answer plus a dot - points to you for pointing this one out though).

Comment: I used `[^\"]` instead of `.`, as it would only match till the next `"`, instead of to the end of the string requiring back tracking.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on which RegEx engine you're using.  Given a Perl or Java engine here's what I see wrong.

`\b` is unnecessary

`\\lyrics\\*` should be `/lyrics/.*` (if Perl, then you'll need to escape the `/` as well.)

Comment: With the escapes for `"` and the fact that the regex is enclosed in `"` and the line ends with `;`, I am assuming Java or C#.

Comment: Though, I'm using Php. It may appear like another language because I'm relatively new to this. Does it make a significant difference?

Comment: In this case, not so much.  There are a number of different regex engines out there and many use the same operators, but some of the command line utilities (e.g. grep) are completely different.  For future regex questions, it would be helpful to indicate where you are using your expression so we don't have to deduce it from the post.  ;)